# problem in calculation in coordinates after rotate the canvas

Tags: android, canvas, rotation, translation

I am working on a sample game demo in which i just put an image in canvas and on android device sensor changes the canvas translate and move for appropriate position. I want to translate canvas just on y-axis (up-down), and rotate it on x-axis. but when i rotate the canvas first time my y-axis coordinates changes and the transformation done on x-axis.

I know the problem with angle of the canvas rotation and calculation of new x,y coordinates but i don't know how to do it.

this is the sample code:

in my activity class

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(int sensor, float[] values) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

              rotateX = values[0]; 
    translateY = values[1];
    Game.setDirection(rotateX,translateY);
}
```

now in Game view class in onDraw() method

```
canvas.rotate(rotateX, imageCenterX, imageCenterY);
canvas.translate(0,translateY);
```

Thanx in advance.

Comment: i am using View class override onDraw method so the code you suggest me    blah.draw(canvas) not working for me. if you are find i am going wrong then please suggest me a code.

Comment: I solved my problem. I just swap the method of canvas.like          canvas.translate(0,translateY);                         canvas.rotate(rotateX, imageCenterX, imageCenterY);                 then it works fine. Emiam thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem.

I just `swap the method of canvas`.

Like

```
canvas.translate(0,translateY); 
canvas.rotate(rotateX, imageCenterX, imageCenterY);
```

Then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be that the changes you make to canvas are not reset. Before you do any changes to canvas(like rotation), call canvas.save(). And then when you're done drawing with those changes, call canvas.restore(). Like this:

```
canvas.save();
canvas.rotate(foo, bar, sar);
blah.draw(canvas);
canvas.restore();
```